# postgres12 alter table with type cast syntax error

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to alter a table with values like below. The data type is a string but I want to change it to numbers.

```
ALTER TABLE data ALTER COLUMN value TYPE NUMERIC(7,2) USING value::numeric 

ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type numeric: "1,000.00"
SQL state: 22P02
```

Comment: 1,000.00 is a string value, you cannot type cast to a numeric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the simple conversion doesn't work.  One method would be:

```
using replace(value, ',', '')::numeric
```

Comment: that worked. I can't upvote because I just signed up. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A more generic approach can be found here:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current//functions-formatting.html
Data Type Formatting Functions
to_number(text, text)   numeric     convert string to numeric

So:

```
select to_number('1,000.00', '99G9999D99');
to_number 
-----------
   1000.00

select pg_typeof(to_number('1,000.00', '99G9999D99'));
 pg_typeof 
-----------
 numeric
```